# Argument in argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I am trying to pass 2 arguments, condition is if the 1st argument is not null, then it should store the 2nd argument. code is shown below

```
import argparse
store= ""
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-one','--two', required = True)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.one != "":
    store = args.two
    print store
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
C:\app\Tools\exam\Python25>python nwe.py -one abc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nwe.py", line 8, in <module>
    if args.one  != "":
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'one'
```

can anyone tell me whats exactly happening

Comment: You have defined 1 argument, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

Yu can use `default` and `parser`:

```
import argparse
store = ""
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--one', help='this is one help', default=None)
parser.add_argument('--two', help='this is two help')

sys_args = vars(parser.parse_args())

print sys_args.get('one')
if sys_args.get('one'):
    print sys_args.get('two')
```

Comment: please check new answer. it say too long , so i have added new answer. Pretty new to stackoverflow, please bear with me  @Kobi K

Answer (score 0):

I think you have glossed over the distinction between long options and short options

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest

`add_argument` creates an Action object.  Your example produces (as shown in an interactive session):

```
In [32]: parser.add_argument('-one','--two', required = True)
Out[32]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-one', '--two'], dest='two', nargs=None, 
    const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

Note that the `dest` is 'two', taken from your '--two'.  '-one' is in the list of `option_strings`, but does not set the `dest`.  This statement creates one Action, not two.

When testing, it is a good idea to print the `args` object.  This gives you a better idea of what your parser produced.  Don't just straight to testing for attributes that might not even be there.

`'prog.py -one value'` and `'prog.py --two value'` will both produce an `args` that looks like

```
Namespace(two='value')
```

and

```
args.two == 'value'
```

If you use both, it's the last value that will appear in the namespace (regardless of order)

If instead you define 2 arguments:

```
parser.add_argument('-o','--one')
parser.add_argument('-t','--two')
```

You can then test/use both after parsing

```
if args.one is None:  # the default default is None, not ""
    store = args.two
    etc
```